# GEE multitemporal segmentation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do I do a multitemporal segmentation in GEE?

Got something like this:

```
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR"),
    ROI = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[10.093076096894833, 55.45897533022183],
          [10.093076096894833, 55.407161055045385],
          [10.231778489472958, 55.407161055045385],
          [10.231778489472958, 55.45897533022183]]], null, false);

// Prepare Image
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var image = S2
  .filterDate("2020-04-01", "2020-12-30")
  .filterBounds(ROI)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  .median()
  .clip(ROI)

// Prepare SNIC
var kernel = ee.Kernel.gaussian(3);
image = image.convolve(kernel);

var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(36);
var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: image,
  compactness: 0,
  connectivity: 8,
  neighborhoodSize: 64,
  size: 3,
  seeds: seeds
}).reproject({
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 10
});
```

But this uses median, so it's not exactly what I want. I would like to make segments from every image and somehow pick the most probable segmentation from that.

Comment: This is an image composition, quite different than a segmentation. What do you mean with segmentation?

Comment: not sure how to answer that... segmentation is pretty well defined in terms of geospatial data

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation (general definition)

Comment: Oh, sorry, got you now. Just remove `median()` line and create a function with the rest of the code, then use `.map`

Comment: but it will create a bunch of segmentations, I need the most probable one... like an median of segmentations not like a median of images and then segmentations.... but median of segmentations won't work.

Comment: Get a time series, apply a dimensional reduction (PCA for instance), and compute segmentation. Most probable segmentation isn't the correct term here, maybe most probable edge is the closest one

Comment: But PCA is not what would work in correctly in this case, as I need the probability factor, because during the year segmentation will change - for example cops will grow. PCA will ruin the point. I tried to make 1 image from all the images (as different bands) but it didn't work.

Comment: 1 image from all images: use `.toBands()`. What I tell you, is something like: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b114008fd4b82d6d58fe580e7616b056

Comment: I know how to do it, but was a concept... I wish it would work, but it doesn't... especially on tile edges... I asked once on how to do a collection of images that will be a mosaic of the closest ones, but no one answered that, so I am asking for other ideas